# Javascript variable not defining in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a small script to clear my search forms when they're clicked on for "only" the first time. So far I have the follow:

```
$(function() {
  if(typeof firstClick == 'undefined') 
  { 
    $("#search").live("focus", function() {
      $(this).val("");
      var firstClick = true;
    });
  }
});
```

However, even with defining the variable with var firstClick = true; in the function, the script seems to pass the if statement every time. I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried defining the var firstClick outside of the function as a false boolean, and then checking to see if it's false or not but I still can't seem to get the variable to go true in the function.

Comment: I don't see how this if block would ever get evaluated more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables exist only in the scope in which they are defined (using `var`) and in descendant scopes. Your `typeof` call is in an ancestor scope. `firstClick` does not exist there.  You should define the variable as `false` in the outer scope, then redefine it as `true`  inside. Furthermore, the conditional should be *inside* the click handler.

```
$(function() {
  var firstClick = false;

  $("#search").live("focus", function() {
    if (!firstClick) {
      $(this).val("");
      firstClick = true; // change the value in the outside scope
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`var firstClick = true;`

You are redeclaring firstClick here. Remove `var`, and define it outside of both functions. Adding `var` before an assignment tells Javascript to make a variable scoped to the current function, which in your case is anonymous function assigned to the focus event. The outer function can't see it since you limited its scope with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `firstClick` var is defined within the local scope of the callback function, thus is not visible to the parent code.

```
var firstClick = false;

$(function() {
  if(!firstClick) 
  { 
    $("#search").live("focus", function() {
      $(this).val("");
      firstClick = true;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of scope. The variable firstClick exists only within the focus event. You need to declare firstClick as a global within the namespace, like so:

```
(function($) {
   var firstClick = false;

   $('#search').live('focus', function() {
        if (typeof firstClick === 'undefined') {
           $(this).val('');
           firstClick = true;
        }
   });
}(jQuery));
```